# List of checkbox in flutter using bloc

Tags: flutter, list, checkbox, bloc

I'm beginner to flutter bloc .

I want to implement list of checkbox in flutter using bloc .
I have seen a code snippet of single checkbox implementation. I need list of checkbox.

is there any documentation available?

and how to pass my list to my cubit.

I have seen a code snippet of single checkbox implementation. I need list of checkbox.

Comment: I think this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72907607/flutter-how-to-implement-checkboxes-with-bloc might help.

Comment: @pixel here the list is passing statically. I want to pass it dynamically.

Comment: @pixel I want to use this dropdown for whole of my app. so the content will be dynamic.so how to pass my dynamic list to cubit

Comment: Yeah than you can have a static list in the cubit and use it. As it's static you will have a single instance and can use from anywhere. And you can have a `ListView.builder` for the dynamic length of the checkbox having length as cubit's length